# if row[0] is equal row[1] then row[2] is None

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I am writing my very first script in Python 2.7. (And this is my very first question/post here and about Python scripting at all)

Solved/found out almost all problems except one.

I can not figure out how to write the following for arcpy.da.UpdateCursor:

**if row[0] is equal row[1] then row[2] is None**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

I am expecting a relevant answer to my question.

EDIT: Here is the working code and a solution to my question.

```
import arcpy

    fc = 'C:/DB/yourDB.gdb/yourFeatureClass.shp'
    fields = ['field0', 'field1', 'field2']
    
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[0] == row[1]):
                row[2] = None
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    
    del cursor
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Also, a quick look in the documentations for [ArcGIS UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm), there is a "Code Sample", "UpdateCursor example 1 " that seems like it could answer your question.

Comment: On a side note, if you are newly learning programming, unless you have a very strong reason to, I would advise you to learn python3 rather than python2.7, as it is deprecated for 3 years now, and I see that ArcGIS does support python3.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply EricChen1248! I figured out what was wrong with the code. I had seen that sample on the page from the link you provided, but just today I got an idea of what I needed to modify. I will comment below the correct code. I'm very grateful for your advice about preferring Python 3 over 2.7. I completely agree with you, but the environment where my script will be used is based on ArcMap 10.2.2 which is using Python 2.7 and that is the "strong reason" you mentioned. I wrote this script in Python 3 and about 70% of the functions were done, then had to rewrite it for 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code and a solution for my question.

```
import arcpy

    fc = 'C:/DB/PGDB.gdb/Parcel_point.shp'
    fields = ['NEWNUMBER', 'NEWNUMBER1', 'NEWNUMBER2']
    
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[0] == row[1]):
                row[2] = None
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    
    del cursor
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).